# More clarification for problem 18.7 Isaacs' Algebra

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Consider the solved problem [Problem 18.7 in I. Martin Isaacs' Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170726/problem-18-7-in-i-martin-isaacs-algebra)

> Let $f(X),g(X) \in F[X]$ and suppose $E \supseteq F$ is the splitting field both for $f(X)$ and for $g(X)$ over $F$. Show that $f(X)$ is separable over $F$ if and only if $g(X)$ is separable over $F$

I can not see where we us that  $E \supseteq F$ is the splitting field **both** for $f(X)$ and for $g(X)$ over $F$.

Any clarification please?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think you should expect that devotees of MSE will have copies of Isaacs’s book to hand. Thus I think it would be better if you outlined the situation in enough detail for readers to be able to answer your question without knowing the text.

Comment: I mention the answered question on StackExchange which have all details. Did you open the link??

Answer (score 1):

In the solution you linked, $g_i(X)$ is an irreducible component of $g(X)$. Since $E$ is separable so **if** $g_i(X)$ has root $\alpha$ in $E$ **then** $g_i(X)$ will be minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and hence $g_i(X)$ has no multiple root.

Since $E$ is splitting field of $g(X)$ so indeed, $\alpha\in E$, and we have the above result.